# TCP/IP parser and responder for C++

Tags: c++, tcp, udp, ip

I have to deal with raw IP packets in C++ because I'm using Open VPN as a library, which delivers IP packets. Therefore, I need a library that keeps responding for me and just deliver the TCP/UDP payload.

I've found [libtrace](https://github.com/LibtraceTeam/libtrace) but it's mean only for parsing. However, I'd still need to manually ACK every TCP packet and keep track of the TCP count etc.

Is there a library that deals with the IP, TCP and UDP layers for me and just deliver the payloads so I can use?

Comment: Libtins check it out, might be of use http://libtins.github.io/

Comment: @Raymond I did a quick read and it looks like a parser/sniffer, but it doesn't looks like it automatically responds the TCP/IP or UDP/IP packets for me and delivers just the payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment and to show you an example taken from [Libtins.](http://libtins.github.io/tutorial/) As you know from my comment, it has the ability to monitor packets. It also has the ability to craft your own payloads and those two combinations allow you to respond, track and monitor with one library.

An example of a [syn scanner](http://libtins.github.io/examples/syn-scanner/) is also provided along with other examples such as an [arp monitor](http://libtins.github.io/examples/arp-monitor/) also. [Filtering](http://libtins.github.io/tutorial/sniffing/) is very easy.

Creating a packet and sending it, can be done in one line

```
EthernetII eth = EthernetII("77:22:33:11:ad:ad", info.hw_addr) / 
                 IP("192.168.0.1", info.ip_addr) /
                 TCP(13, 15) /
                 RawPDU("PAYLOAD");
```

and again you could expand on this

```
#include <tins/tins.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace Tins;

int main() {
    // We'll use the default interface(default gateway)
    NetworkInterface iface = NetworkInterface::default_interface();

    /* Retrieve this structure which holds the interface's IP, 
     * broadcast, hardware address and the network mask.
     */
    NetworkInterface::Info info = iface.addresses();

    /* Create an Ethernet II PDU which will be sent to 
     * 77:22:33:11:ad:ad using the default interface's hardware 
     * address as the sender.
     */
    EthernetII eth("77:22:33:11:ad:ad", info.hw_addr);

    /* Create an IP PDU, with 192.168.0.1 as the destination address
     * and the default interface's IP address as the sender.
     */
    eth /= IP("192.168.0.1", info.ip_addr);

    /* Create a TCP PDU using 13 as the destination port, and 15 
     * as the source port.
     */
    eth /= TCP(13, 15);

    /* Create a RawPDU containing the string "I'm a payload!".
     */
    eth /= RawPDU("I'm a payload!");

    // The actual sender
    PacketSender sender;

    // Send the packet through the default interface
    sender.send(eth, iface);
}
```